# How to stack editors in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Xcode 3 had the nifty widget [image: widget]
 that split an editing screen in two.  I don't see that in Xcode 4.  Has Apple decided that I don't need that anymore? ;-)

Comment: So I have to open the Assistant, then in the assistant's jump bar, select "Manual", and then navigate to where I need to go.  But I can only have 2 open.  The split widget and the jump to .h/.m will be sorely missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Middle button under the "Editors" in the top right will split beside each other.  I don't likd that as much as the stacking one in xcode 3 though...

EDIT: You probably have to navigate to the same file to get it "split".  Again, not as easy as xcode 3...

Comment: You can choose the layout (side-by-side or top-and-bottom) of the assistant editor using View -> Assistant Layout.